# Can't use the socket after relaunching it

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, bufferedreader, outputstream

I had create a new client-server connection using ordinary java socket programming:

```
private static BufferedReader input;
private static DataOutputStream output;
private static Socket socket;
public void connect() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I'm sending and receiving the following way :

**to send:**

```
output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
output.writeBytes(data);
```

**to receive:**

```
    InputStream stream = null;
    try{
        stream = socket.getInputStream();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(stream != null){
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                stream));

    // some input processing
    }
```

The problem is when The connection is interrupted some how I have to relaunch it again in the app run-time, so I made a thread in order to re-execute the `connect()` method, and It executed efficiently without any Exceptions, but then , the `input` and `output` variables fail to send or receive any data.

Comment: Trying to mix binary data and text data usually leads to confusion unless you really know what you are doing.  I suggest using text only to start with as this is easier to debug.

Comment: Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of the try block should be inside the truth block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are reconnecting your socket without recreating your input and output streams.

Try running recreating your input and output streams after you run connect() like so:

```
output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
stream = socket.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try cleaning the input and output stream in finally and also close the socket...

```
finally { socket.close(); }
```